# Check input checkbox inside Angular2 code

Tags: html, angular, checkbox

I am having problems changing the checked value of an input.

I am using the following :

> this.renderer.setElementAttribute(event.srcElement.parentElement.firstElementChild,"checked","true");

Where the firstElementChild is the respective  to be "checked"

Comment: Please add your code to the question so that others can help.

Comment: I have also tried to use this.renderer.setElementPropert with no sucess

Comment: I wouldn't use the Renderer for this task. Use data binding to link the checkbox to a component property. Then to check the box, just set the component property and let Angular update the view for you